# Is this query possible?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a video website where each video is in a category and i want to display the most watched video from each category.

The video hits have a table of their own where each hit records the user_id and video_id

The part im struggling with is counting the hits where if a single user watches a video ten times it still only counts the one hit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))
FROM video_hits
WHERE video_id = '1826'
```

It should give the total number of users who have watched the video with id 1826

EDIT: I have only tested this in MS SQL because I am at work at the moment - I can check it out in MySQL when I get home, but I assume it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

> if a single user watches a video ten times it still only counts the one hit.

Use COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)

> The part im struggling with...

Does that mean you've solved the problem of getting the top video from each category? That's a much more complicated problem in SQL ([the max-concat trick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html))

Comment: I **think** I have the rest sorted, it includes some other tables I didn't mention:- SELECT
 COUNT(DISTINCT views.user_id) as hits,
 
 categories.name as cat_name,
 categories.url as cat_url,
 
 videos.id as video_id,
 videos.title as title,
 videos.file_still as image,
 
 users.username as nickname,
 
 series.url as series_url
 
FROM `categories`

JOIN videos ON videos.category_id = categories.id
JOIN users ON videos.user_id = users.id
JOIN views ON videos.id = views.video_id
JOIN series ON videos.series_id = series.id

GROUP BY categories.id

ORDER BY categories.name, hits DESC

LIMIT 6

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are stopping the hit table from inserting duplicate records? You should do this so that you can perform a select count(id) where user_id = ?? and video_id = ??. This will return the number of times these two parameters have occurred in the table.

Comment: So instead of searching for unique results, I should only have unique results in the table in the first place. I had this in the back of my mind but didn't want to go down that route.. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, my thought was either what I suggested or stick a new column in and every time a user watches a video check to see if they have watched it previously, if so increment views if not create a new record?